# Having difficulty solving basic RubyMonk exercise

Tags: ruby

On this page:
https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/105-equality_of_objects

I am trying to correct this code, so that it passes its tests.
My attempt is quite bad as I am only just beginning to learn how software logic works.

```
class Item
    attr_reader :item_name, :qty

    def initialize(item_name, qty)
        @item_name = item_name
        @qty = qty
    end
    def to_s
        "Item (#{@item_name}, #{@qty})"
    end

    def ==(other_item)
    end
end

p Item.new("abcd",1)  == Item.new("abcd",1)
p Item.new("abcd",2)  == Item.new("abcd",1)
```

This is my solution, but it is not correct:

```
class Item
    attr_reader :item_name, :qty

    def initialize(item_name, qty)
        @item_name = item_name
        @qty = qty
    end
    def to_s
        "Item (#{@item_name}, #{@qty})"
    end

    def ==(other_item)
       if self == other_item
         return true
       else
         return false
       end
    end
end

p Item.new("abcd",1)  == Item.new("abcd",1)
p Item.new("abcd",2)  == Item.new("abcd",1)
```

I was hoping a Rubyist out there could help me solve this exercise.  I am unsure of how to solve it.

Thanks for your help

here is the output from the test:

```
STDOUT:
nil
nil
Items with same item name and quantity should be equal
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
expected Item (abcd, 1) got Item (abcd, 1) (compared using ==) Diff:
Items with same item name but different quantity should not be equal ✔
Items with same same quantity but different item name should not be equal ✔
```

Comment: You need to change your `==` method so that, in the case that `self` is not `other_item` but they have the same name (`self.item_name == other_item.item_name`) and same value (sim. for `qty`), it returns `true`. (Actually, calling `==` on an object within the definition of `==` for that class should put you into infinite recursion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you override the `==` method, you should give meaning to your comparison. The default `==` behavior checks that the other item is *identical* to the compared item (they have the same object_id). Try this:

```
def ==(other_item)
   other_item.is_a?(Item) && 
     self.item_name == other_item.item_name && 
     self.qty == other_item.qty
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Can point you in right direction instead of telling the answer.

You are comparing the references of objects for equality, whereas, you are **asked** to compare only those attributes for equality. That is, compare both objects parameters in such a way that if they are equal, it must return `true`; else `false`

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll down past the question you will see that the next example provides a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ==(other_item)
  self.item_name == other_item.item_name && 
  self.qty == other_item.qty
end
```

end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).